# Programmatically call AVPlayerViewController's fullscreen button

Tags: ios, fullscreen, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an AVPlayer wrapped with AVPlayerViewController. My entire app is in portrait mode and AVPlayer is subview of one of the view. I want to make the video full screen automatically when device is rotated like youtube app. Is there any way to programmatically call AVPlayerViewController's fullscreen button method. Didn't find anything in documentation.